# Discord.js v13. | voiceStateUpdate Event

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is a bot that plays an audio per command in vc (on Discord server 1). But on Discord server 2, the bot should always be in a vc, and not leaven when no one (except itself) is in the vc.

So the bot should always stay in the talk channel 1073655275141210122 on Discord server 1, even if it is alone in that talk. On server 2, on the other hand, the bot should always stay in the voice channel or VC when no one else is in it (except the bot itself).

*My problem*: The bot leavens on both channels as soon as there is no one in them.

**My current code:**

```js
// Voice State Update Event

client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {

    const state = newState || oldState

    if(state.channelId == '1073655275141210122') {
        return;
    }

    if (oldState.channelID !==  oldState.guild.me.voice.channelID || newState.channel){
        return; 
    }

    if(oldState.channel.members.size == 1 && oldState.channel.members.get(client.user.id)){
        
        
        newState.guild.me.voice.disconnect(); 
    }
    
});
```

I have already tried:

```js
if(state.channelId == '1073655275141210122') return
```

&

```js
if (oldState.channelID !==  oldState.guild.me.voice.channelID || !newState.channel)
```

but it doesn't matter.

Comment: You don't check the guild ID anywhere, do you?

Comment: no, I don't check the Guild ID of the server on which bot should stay in the voice channel.